# Xamarin Check If Column exist in DB Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want a simple and fast way to see if a specific name exists in a sqlite database in Xamarin. I tried too many ways like this but it either returns all true or all false.

```
 public bool Check(string Name)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "PictureDB_GM.db3")))
            {
                if (connection.Query<PictureDB>("SELECT * FROM Person Where Name=?", Name) == null)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

For now, I am using this:

```
        for (int y = 0; y < lstSource.Count; y++)
        {

            if (lstSource[y].Name == view.Resources.GetResourceName(item.ImageResourceId))
            {

                ImageService.Instance.LoadCompiledResource(view.Resources.GetText(Resource.Drawable.Truee)).Into(img_2);

                break;
            }
            else
                ImageService.Instance.LoadCompiledResource(view.Resources.GetText(Resource.Drawable.empty)).Into(img_2);

        }
```

It works fine with few entries, but it takes a long amount of time and makes the app buggy and starts crushing if the DB has more than 50 entries.

So is there any clean way or a better way to do this ??

Comment: maintaining the connection and not recreating it each time you need to check a file name might help your issues. Also using a basic ORM https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/data-and-cloud-services/data-access/using-sqlite-orm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better preformence by using this

```
    if(MainActivity.db.selectTablePerson().Where(i => i.Name == view.Resources.GetResourceName(item.ImageResourceId)).FirstOrDefault()==null)
            ImageService.Instance.LoadCompiledResource(view.Resources.GetText(Resource.Drawable.empty)).Into(img_2);
        else
            ImageService.Instance.LoadCompiledResource(view.Resources.GetText(Resource.Drawable.Truee)).Into(img_2);
```